# I want to know why this works without having to bind memory for the string

Tags: c, string, pointers, string-literals

Hello guys I recently picked up C programming and I am stuck at understanding pointers. As far as I understand to store a value in a pointer you have to bind memory (using malloc) the size of the value you want to store. Given this, the following code should not work as I have not allocated 11 bytes of memory to store my string of size 11 bytes and yet for some reason beyond my comprehension it works perfectly fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

  char *str = NULL;

  str = "hello world\0";
  printf("filename = %s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to put `\0` at the end. The string literal does that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a string literal in a C program, it is stored in a [read-only section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2589963/1679849) of the program code. A statement of the form `char *str = "hello";` will assign the address of this string to the `char*` pointer. However, the string itself (i.e., the characters `h`, `e`, `l`, `l` and `o`, plus the `\0` string terminator) are still located in read-only memory, so you can't change them at all.

Note that there's no need for you to explicitly add a zero byte terminator to your string declarations. The C compiler will do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

In this case

```
 str = "hello world\0";
```

`str` points to the address of the first element of an array of `chars`, initialized with `"hello world\0"`. In other words, `str` points to a "string literal".

By definition, the array is allocated and the address of the first element has to be "valid".

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.5, *String literals*

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
>   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.<sup>78)</sup> The multibyte character
>   sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have
>   type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
>   sequence. [....]

Memory allocation **still** happens, just **not explicitly** by you (via memory allocator functions).

---

That said, the `"...\0"` at the end is repetitive, as mentioned (in the first statement of the quote) above, by default, the array will be null-terminated.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `char` variable without `malloc` is stating that the string you are assigning is read-only. This means  that you are creating a pointer to a string constant. `"hello world\0"` is somewhere in the read-only part of memory and you are just pointing to it.

Now if you want to make changes to the string. Let's say changing the `h` to `H`, that would be `str[0]='H'`. Without `malloc` that will not be possible to make.

Answer (score 1):

Right. But in this case you are just pointing to a string literal which is placed in the constant memory area. Your pointer is created in the stack area. So you are just pointing to another address. i.e, at the starting address of string literal.

Try using copy the string literal in your pointer variable. Then it will give error because you have not allocated memory. Hope you understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Storage for string literals is set aside at program startup and held until the program exits.  This storage *may* be read-only, and attempting to modify the contents of a string literal results in undefined behavior (it may work, it may crash, it may do something in between).